# List items of dropdown have transparent background after navbar collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've been working on a custom menu and i'm having trouble with the collapsed menu, and a drop down menu list item contained in it. When you look with viewport after the navbar collapses and you click the dropdown "Dropdown" the four list elements have a transparent background when you hover over them, and if you scroll down the page when the viewport is the size of a mobile the dropdown elements don't scroll as well.

I have my **overflow-y** as visible because I want the user to be able to scroll down the page, ideally with an accordion style for the collapsed dropdown list items (which I can't figure out), and not have a separate scroll bar just for the dropdown. Is there a way to have it so the collapsed, dropdown list items don't have a transparent background and the menu that has been dropped down can be scrolled with the regular page scroller? I hope that's coherent enough lol, let me know if this should be two questions. I've included my HTML and full CSS

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1"  aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h2>LOGO</h2></a></div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">



    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right links">
      <li><a href="#"><h5>Link 1</h5></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><h5>Link 2</h5></a></li>

      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-parent="#accordion" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><h5>Dropdown</h5></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a><span class="label label-danger  home-label" >Give us a call! &nbsp;</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

**CSS File**

```
@media (min-width: 991px) {
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}
}
body{
padding-top: 120px; 
background-color:#34A0CD;
}


.navbar-default{
height:120px;
}
.navbar-header, .navbar-brand{
height:120px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;   
}
home-label{
font-size:17px;
margin-right:35px;

}
.navbar-nav li span{
font-size:17px;
margin-right:35px;
line-height:130px;
}

#topFixedNavbar1{
height:120px;
}
.links{
height:120px;

}
.navbar-nav li a h5{
line-height:80px;
}
.dropdown li a {
line-height:30px;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
.dropdown li a{
    line-height:30px;
}

.collapse.navbar-collapse{
    width:100%;

}
.links li a{

    width:100%;
}

.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus
{
background-color: gray;
}
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent ;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);

}

.navbar-collapse.in {
overflow-y: visible;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;

}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;

}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav li a h5{
line-height: 15px;
background-color: gray;
color: #F1E9E9;     
}
.navbar-nav li a span{
    line-height:15px;
    background-color:gray;
}
.navbar-nav li a{
    background-color:gray;
    width:100%;
}


.navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
/* since 3.1.0 */
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
    display: block!important;
}
.collapsing {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navbar-fixed-top` class makes the `nav` to be fixed element and you cannot make a fixed element scrollable without declaring specific width/height to it. So, I

- removed `navbar-fixed-top` from `navbar`
- removed `padding-top: 120px;` on `body` to align the `navbar` to top
- made some changes on dropdown for the transparent background issue.

  ```
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
      .navbar-nav li.open a h5 {
          color: black;
          background: 0 0;
      }
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
          color: white;
      }
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
          background-color: white;
          color: black;
      }
  }
  ```

  you can change the "theme" as you like.

check it in [action](https://jsfiddle.net/se6ug2q5/2/)

Comment: Awesome that took care of the transparent background, although it still is transparent if you hit the arrow buttons through the collapsed drop down menu list items but I can worry about that later. Only problem is if the screen size is about mobile phone size to where the dropdown items go off screen when opened you can't scroll down to see those off-screen. You can on the jsfiddle demo when the screen is resized, but not when I do it via Chrome, Firefox etc. Do you think it could just be my computer because it was perfect on your jsfiddle demo.

Comment: along with `hover`, i added `focus` to fix the transparent background issue but i don't see any problem when checked as a separate file on chrome and firefox.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the inability to scroll when the collapsed drop down list items appear off-screen will look differently when viewed through an actual mobile phone. Anyway, that was really a secondary question my main problem of the transparent drop down on collapse is good to go thanks to you, I appreciate it!